# SharePoint Copy List Item

Tags: c#, sharepoint, copy, listitem

I got a problem to copy a list item. Do you see the mistake?

When ExecuteQuery() is triggered it throws the exception you can see at the end of this post.

If I comment out the foreach(), there is no exception

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(ctx);
            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                clientContext.Load(list, l => l.Fields);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var sourceItem = list.GetItemById(sourceItemId);
                clientContext.Load(sourceItem);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                var sourceItemValues = sourceItem.FieldValues;

                var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                var targetItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

                foreach (var field in list.Fields)
                {
                    if (!field.ReadOnlyField && !field.InternalName.Equals("Attachments"))
                    {
                        object val = null;
                        sourceItemValues.TryGetValue(field.InternalName, out val);
                        targetItem[field.InternalName] = val;
                    }
                }

                targetItem.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Exception:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Invalid request.
   bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   bei [...]
   bei lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   bei System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Whats targetItem.Item? I only got properties like Id, DisplayName, FieldValues... but not .Item?

Comment: `ListItem.Item` (according to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.item.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) is a property for accessing field values by internal name. Contrary to my earlier comment, you would use bracket notation to access it, like `targetItem.Item[field.InternalName] = val;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### SOLVED

The Request can't be Executed because the ContentType is not allowed to be changed.

This line (replaces the line above) solved the problem:

```
   if (!field.ReadOnlyField && !field.InternalName.Equals("Attachments") && !field.InternalName.Equals("ContentType"))
```